# java -target compile

Tags: java, compiler-construction

How do I compile a java program in a different version if I have 1.6 and I want it compiled in 1.5? Would it be like...

> javac -target1.5 tileGen

But when I do that I get:

error: Class names, 'tileGen', are only accepted if annotation processing is exp
licitly requested
1 error

Comment: Also, be careful of the difference between the "target" and "source" command line options.  "target" specifies the version for the output of the compiler; i.e., the class files.  "source" specifies the version for the source code; i.e., the *.java files.  I know your error in the above statement is that you left off the ".java" extension, but I think this clarification on the source and target arguments is worth having associated with this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `javac` takes the name of a source file (ending in `.java) not the name of a class.

Try

```
javac -target 1.5 tileGen.java
```

instead.

Comment: Oh WHOOPS! Rookie mistake. Haha!

Comment: Thanks you and digitalsanctum

Comment: No problem. It's one of the least helpful error messages I've come across!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding .java to your class name